# Porting large Rust project to Solana

Tags: solana-program

I'm trying to port the VM of https://github.com/oxfeeefeee/goscript to Solana. I did some research, and it seems I need to:

1. Make a no_async feature.
2. Limit memory usage.

What else should be on the list? Could someone familiar with on chain programming limitations help please, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[These](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#restrictions) are the on-chain restrictions that apply to the Rust code. For example, I noticed some instances of unsafe Rust in the code that will not work on-chain.

These restrictions apply to both your code and the dependencies. The latter will make it quite tricky even if you manage to get around them in your own code.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that. The problem is it's too vague. For example, it lists "std::future", I though it means the std version is not supported, when in fact an "async" keyword crashes the compiler.

Comment: Previously, I just had to keep changing things and compiling till it got somewhere. I am yet to find a better way of doing this.